# it displays only text,but not the image

Tags: blackberry

i developed the code as below.in this i used listfield  ,one bitmapfield and one label field,when i will run it ,it displays only text on the list field row,but not the image 
i don't know where i did mistake,so,plz,any one help me to know where i did mistake
thanks for any help

```
class TaskListField extends MainScreen implements ListFieldCallback {
         private Vector rows;
         private Bitmap p1;
ListField list;
         TableRowManager row;
         public TaskListField() {
          super();
          list=new ListField() {

              protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
              }

};
          list.setRowHeight(40);
          list.setEmptyString("Hooray, no tasks here!", DrawStyle.HCENTER);
          list.setCallback(this);

          p1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/images/10.png");
 rows = new Vector();

          for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++) {
            row = new TableRowManager();
             LabelField task = new LabelField("" + String.valueOf(x),
             DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS);
   row.add(task);
           row.add(new BitmapField(p1));
  rows.addElement(row);
          }
          list.setSize(rows.size());
add(list);
         }

         // ListFieldCallback Implementation
         public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index, int y,
           int width) {

          TableRowManager rowManager = (TableRowManager) rows
            .elementAt(index);
          rowManager.drawRow(g, 0, y, width, list.getRowHeight());
         }

         private class TableRowManager extends Manager {
          public TableRowManager() {
           super(0);
          }
  public void drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

           layout(width, height);


           setPosition(x, y);


           g.pushRegion(getExtent());

           // Paint this manager's controlled fields.
           subpaint(g);

           g.setColor(0x00CACACA);
           g.drawLine(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), 0);

           // Restore the graphics context.
           g.popContext();
          }


          protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {

           int preferredWidth = getPreferredWidth();


           Field field = getField(0);
           layoutChild(field, 30, 30);
           setPositionChild(field, 0, 0);


          field = getField(1);
           layoutChild(field, 40, 25);
           setPositionChild(field, 120, 10);
  setExtent(preferredWidth, getPreferredHeight());
          }

          // The preferred width of a row is defined by the list renderer.
          public int getPreferredWidth() {
           return Graphics.getScreenWidth();
          }

          // The preferred height of a row is the "row height" as defined in the
          // enclosing list.
          public int getPreferredHeight() {
           return list.getRowHeight();
          }
         }

         public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return null;
         }

         public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return 0;
         }

         public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return 0;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the bitmap is not null? I would check that first -- perhaps it's not finding the resource.

Comment: Just to add to Eric's answer (since I had a problem with not finding resources). If that bitmap is null, and you know the name is set correctly, and the bitmap is in a subfolder of the res folder.... then you may need to _include_ that subfolder into the project. Right click folder, choose Build Path... Include. hth

Answer (score 0):

Could the LabelField be taking the entire width of the screen (it does that on certain situations)? When you only set the image without setting the label, does the image show?

Answer (score 0):

The image path is not necessary as you put it

```
p1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource (" res/images/10.png ");
```

only needs

```
p1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource (" 10.png ");
```